# How to retrieve list of dates that is partially stored in the database and bind it in gridview in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, date, gridview, listitem

I want to dynamically display list of dates in grid view. The dates should be row by row and retrieved from the database.

Below are the example of data from database :

```
DSB_Date   GloveID    DSB_BalQty  DSB_Sizes
3/7/2017    ABC123     100          M
3/7/2017    ABC123     200          XL
7/7/2017    ABC123     150          L
7/7/2017    ABC123     780          M
```

As you can see there are no records from 4th July to 6th July.
But I still want them to be in the grid view. I want to have below kind of output:

```
GloveID : ABC123
Date          M     L    XL
3/7/2017     100    0   200     
4/7/2017      0     0    0    
5/7/2017      0     0    0
6/7/2017      0     0    0
7/7/2017     780   150   0
```

it should be listing the whole date for respective month. I am not using any drop down list to populate the data.

The record which displayed the grid view is retrieved from another page by Glove ID. Let say from Page A, click at the hyperlink and the URL will pass the Glove ID and redirect to Page B which list all the information.

Below are the SQL Query that I used to display the size and quantity

```
 select DSB.GloveID, G.GloveCode, DSB_Month, DSB_Year, DSB_Date, 

      max(case when DSB_Sizes = 'M' then DSB_BalQty else 0 end) M,
      max(case when DSB_Sizes = 'L' then DSB_BalQty else 0 end) L,
      max(case when DSB_Sizes = 'XL' then DSB_BalQty else 0 end) XL     

  from tblDailyStockBal DSB

    left join tblGlove G on G.GloveID = DSB.GloveID

    where DSB.GloveID = @GloveID 
    group by DSB.GloveID, G.GloveCode, DSB_Month, DSB_Year, DSB_Date
```

How can I achieved that **date** things in C#?
I've tried below approached but still not getting what I wish for.

1. [How to create a Gridview that has number of days as column based on month selection](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/757344/How-to-create-a-Gridview-that-has-number-of-days-a)
2. [display dates row wish of select month in gridview using asp.net](http://display%20dates%20row%20wish%20of%20select%20month%20in%20gridview%20using%20asp.net)

Comment: You need provide more details about your code, how do you retrieve data in c# from mysql?

Comment: For now, I just retrieved the whole data using Gridview DataBind
Example :
GridView1.DataSource = mtsc.SelectAllByGloveID(gloveID);
GridView1.DataBind();

I have no idea at all how to list the date and bind it again.

Comment: I recommend to use a repeater and inside of item template use a gridview to show data in that format

Comment: You mean using repeater control? Can I use Datetime to retrieve **date** information? I am thinking on getting a month from the database, then use datetime to get total number of day of that month and list all the dates. Is it how it suppose to work?

Comment: Yes, I think you need to use two queries, the first to retrieve dates list and the second to retrieve the details for each date or make only one query and from c# side create grouped data (each date with details)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use two date string to check is data available or not between two string like,

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * (or column name,column name)FROM dbo.name where Date between '" + @date1+ "' and '" +@date2 + "' order by Date desc", connection);
                SqlDataAdapter sd1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
                sd1.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataSet dst1 = new DataSet();
                sd1.Fill(dst1, "table name");


               yourgridview.DataSource = dst1.Tables[0];
```

this is basic idea for this,i hope you get the logic,and use proper secure connection as well,,,

Comment: Okay I kind of get the ideas there. But I am thinking on how to list all the **dates**. For example July got 31 days. How to make the system list all the dates? and bind it with the grid view?

Comment: provide datepicker to user so he can select date and search using those date,,i hope this this what u want,if not provide some info what u want or expect from your application,,,